# getting undefined values use each jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

```
var returnResponse = function (click, toElement, getParser) {
$("body").on('change', click, function (event) {    
        $(toElement).empty();
        removeExistingDataFull();    
        $.ajax({    
            url: "../Controller/jsonParser.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: getParser + '=' + $(click).val(),
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (response) {    
                $(response).each(function () {
                    console.log(this.getParser);
                    $(toElement).append($("<option>").attr('value', this.getParser).text(this.getParser));    
                });
            }
        });
    });
};


returnResponse('#CouserFinder', '#RegType', 'CT_Course_Code');
```

Here is `the console.log(this);` output

[image]

But when i used  `console.log(this.getParser);`,It show me undefined

Here is the console log output
[image]

What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Why do you expect there to be a "getParser" property? What exactly does the JSON response look like?

Comment: @Pointy `getParser` `=``CT_Type_Code`. So. when i used `console.log(getParser);` it show me `CT_Type_Code` as well

Comment: OH I see.  Yes, see Mr. Crowder's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for bracketed notation:

```
$(toElement).append($("<option>").attr('value', this[getParser]).text(this[getParser]));
// -------------------------------------------------^---------^-----------^---------^
```

In JavaScript, you can access a property in one of two ways:

1. Using *literal* ("dotted") syntax, `foo.bar`, and
2. Using string ("bracketed") syntax, `foo["bar"]`

In the second case, the string can be the result of any expression, including a variable lookup. So `this[getParser]` will look up whatever property is named by the string in `getParser`. If `getParser` is `"CT_Course_Code"`, then `this[getParser]` will look up the `CT_Course_Code` on `this`.

---

Side note: Your code is looking for `CT_Course_Code` property, but your screenshot suggests that the objects in the `response` array don't *have* a `CT_Course_Code` property. They do have `CT_Type_Code`, though. That's assuming `response` *is* an array, it's hard to tell as you haven't shown us the actual JSON being returned.

Comment: @samitha: See the side note I added to the answer.

Comment: @samitha: I'm not following, the code is fine if you use bracketed notation, provided you look for a property that exists. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
  $.each(response, function( index, value ) {
         console.log( index + ": " + value );
         $(toElement).append($("<option>").attr('value', value ).text(value ));

   });
```